# Restricting the DeRham cohomology class of a submanifold to a coordinate neighborhood.

Tags: differential-geometry, homology-cohomology

Suppose $M$ is an $n$-manifold and $A$ a $k$-dimensional submanifold, both compact and oriented.  Let the deRham cohomology class of $A$ be denoted $[\phi_A]$.  The class is defined by $$\int_M\phi_A\wedge\omega=\int_A\omega$$ for every closed $k$-form $\omega$ on $M$.

If $U$ is a coordinate neighborhood does it follow that $$\int_U\phi_A\wedge\omega=\int_{A\cap U}\omega$$ for every closed $k$-form $\omega$ on $M$?

Here we take restrictions of forms as necessary so that the statements make sense.

Comment: What do you mean by $\int_{A \cap U} \omega$ if $A \cap U$ is not a compact oriented submanifold of $U$?

Comment: Since $A\cap U$ has a single coordinate chart the integral makes, sense, right?

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\phi_A$ is defined up to an exact form form $d\alpha$ and

$$\int_U (\phi_A + d\alpha) \wedge \omega = \int_U \phi_A \wedge \omega + \int_U d(\alpha\wedge w)$$

and

$$\int_U d(\alpha\wedge \omega) = \int_{\partial U} \alpha \wedge \omega$$

So the LHS of your equation is not well defined if $\partial U \neq \emptyset$.

If you consider that $\omega$ is of compact support in $U$, then you can extend $\omega$ by $0$ to $M$, and everything reduces to your first equation.

Comment: If I'm not mistake, $U$ wouldn't have boundary as a manifold, only topological boundary in $M$.  So I'm not sure that this is a problem.  Do you agree with me or disagree?

Comment: I think the problem is that Poincare duality generally do not apply on non-closed manifolds and submanifolds. One can take $U$ to have smooth boundary so that Stokes theorem applies. @Seth